# Strongly typed htmlhelper & spark

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, spark-view-engine, strong-typing

I read [that it's](http://groups.google.com/group/spark-dev/browse_thread/thread/618bd44a94368d22/777d3a32abd4fe46?show_docid=777d3a32abd4fe46) possible, but didn't get idea how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [development build](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts&buildTypeId=bt47) is acceptable solution for me (it works with that)...